# Win2k8 Server 64bit | Crystal Repor 2005 - Exception: Load report failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2008

We are migrating to **Windows Server 2008 R2 x64** from **Windows Server 2003 x86**

We usually have a fully documented setups and procedures on migrations which **proven & working on windows Server 2003 x86** since we already done more 5x in less than 3 years in a roll.

But now on **Win2k8 Server R2 x64**, we still followed the above, the only additional/new procedure is to install:

- vcredist_x86 (since the usual VS2005_CR installer is failing, need to installed this first, then the usual VS2005_CR installer).

We also tried to installed (hoping below problem will be fixed):

- CRRedist2005_X64

Crystal Report, Create a pdf files on a certain directory and we have a form that streams the pdf. (take note access right to this directory (whole application path "\kiss") is set FULL to EVERYONE)

**but still no avail, We still  have below issue:**

**Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.**

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**Stack Trace:**

```
[AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +65
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +195

[Exception: Load report failed.]
   CompanyMatrix.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\www\kiss\Matrixes\CompanyMatrix.aspx.cs:134
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   OSM.kiss.Web.BaseWebUI.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

**Additional Info:**
We can exclude the possibility of Folder Access Rights, since the App can generate xls, docs and .txt on the folder it self.

Comment: P.S. I have to say Win2008R2 is way more secure than older versions of WinServer, disallowing access to registry keys, it's more difficult to write to the GAC etc. etc.

Comment: @Colin, do you have suggestion on my issue?

Comment: Do you have 64-bit developer machines?  Does it work on them?

Comment: @Jeremy Stein, that's the problem is, we don't have 64-bit developer